# How to get tid by pthread_self() properly?

Tags: linux, pthreads

As I mentioned in title, I tried to get `tid` (thread id) by `pthread_self()`. (The reason I did it because I tried to avoid system call)

I know there maybe didn't have portable solution, it's fine. I'm searching for solution works on specific environment.

My target environment is using POSIX pthread and

glibc version is ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.1) 2.31

Running under Ubuntu 20.04.

Following is what I did so far,

I tried to cast return value of `pthread_self` to `strcut pthread` which has `tid` as member. Also, get into definition of `struct pthread` by [link](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/descr.h;hb=HEAD#l123), there're two members in front of `tid`.

```cpp
struct pthread_fake
{
    void *dummy[2];
    pid_t tid;
};
...
printf("%d\n", ((struct pthread_fake *)pthread_self())->tid)
```

The result is not right, anything I do wrong?

Comment: Do you have some particular reason to think `pthread_self` is more efficient than `gettid`? Is that just a hunch?

Comment: System call has some overhead like mode change, I think it's costly. (compare to lookup only)

Comment: Have you measured the cost of the `gettid` call?  Have you verified that it's the bottleneck in your particular case by benchmarking and measuring appropriately?  If not, it seems like a premature optimization to avoid `gettid` in favor of trying to dig around in `struct pthread_t` like this.

Comment: @bk2204, yes, I did.